# Как сделать, чтобы картинка была тусклой, а при наведении мышкой - нормальной?

Tags: css

Только не через opacity. [Вот тут смотрите на слайдер](http://dzyngiri.com/demo/codester/)

Как он сделан(именно тусклая часть)

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь, например, свойством opacity.
http://htmlbook.ru/css/opacity

Вместе с псевдоклассом :hover
http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover

для блока с картинкой установите opacity меньше единицы, а в дополнительном стиле с использованием :hover, восстанавливайте прозрачность.

```
#image {
opacity: 0.5;
}
#image:hover {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: прошу прощения) как-то я не особо вчитался в вопрос)

Comment: Очень похоже на костыль) но возможно вам подойдет)

http://jsfiddle.net/TwZRu/3/

Comment: Ответ уже убрали, вот его форк. Без слова opacity, как просил ТС
http://jsfiddle.net/E2R8x/4/

Comment: Убрал ответ тк понял что накладывать оверлай тоже самое что применять опасити к картинке на серый(синий) фон.

А автор требоует видимо что то другое. Хотя на сайте который он указал явно опасити на серо-синий цвет ;)

Comment: странно что rgba никто не вспомнил http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/TwZRu/8/

Comment: А почему автор решил что на том слайдере не через опасити сделано?? , Там как раз атрибут опасити установлен на 0,6.